# Can I omit the second "had he" in "Had he been honest and had he told that"

Tags: tense-agreement

My first question is if I can omit the "had he" in front of "told"?

> Had he been honest and **told** that only the photo of an outdated engine, that had been already printed by others years before, would be published, the interest of his readers, in buying the next issue of his periodical, would have been much lower.

Another question would be if the tense agreement is good for the entire sentence which is about an author who dishonestly promised (just to make the readers curious) he would publish the picture of a revolutionary engine in the next issue of his magazine but finally only a picture of an outdated motor was printed.

Comment: "had he told that" isn't really good English. Told who?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Had he been honest and told his readers that he would publish the photo of an outdated engine, which had already been printed by others years before, their interest in buying the next issue of his periodical would have been much lower.

Yes you can omit 'had he' in front of told because it is understood to still apply.

I've amended the rest of the sentence for clarity and brevity.

Comment: This is a much better, less confusing version of the sentence.